# Directory target is always up to date

Tags: scons

I'm trying to update the files in a directory with a command like:

```
env.Command(Dir("./targetdir/"),
            ["./targetdir/file0", "./targetdir/file1", ...],
            "./somescript.sh $TARGET")
```

Scons keeps telling me that `./targetdir/` is up to date, even though I've modified by hand `./targetdir/file0.`

Isn't scons supposed to know that, since one source file has changed, the command should be run? Is there a particularity with the fact that the target is a directory?

I want to run the command `./somescript.sh ./targetdir/` whenever any of the file in `./targetdir/` changes. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you intend for targetdir/file0, etc to be a source and a target?

Comment: So, you want if one of file in list (in targetdir) is changed you want to call somescript.sh with every file that will changed, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you have no target. Scons can't store information about dependency without having target and source. 
So, one of solution use explicit target.

```
mycmd = Command('some_target', [], ['script.sh targetdir', Touch('$TARGET')])
or 
mycmd = Command('some_target', [], 'script.sh targetdir > $TARGET')
Depends(mycmd, Glob('targetdir/*'))
```

Now, scons have target named some_target and known that it depends from files in targetdir. IMHO, best way create special builder/wrapper for it and use variant dirs to store targets there.

Answer (score 1):

I dont beleive SCons likes the target to be a directory. You should instead specify the individual file(s) as the target.

As a side note, do you intend for the target and source to contain the same files? If this is for lack of an input file for "somescript.sh", typically you can just provide the script as the source. This way SCons will compare the target with the script, as opposed to the target with itself.

```
env.Command(target = "#targetdir/file0",
            source = "#somescript.sh",
            action = "#somescript.sh $TARGET")
```

Notice I use "#" in the path, which means relative to the root SConsctruct.

Comment: I don't really understand why provide the script as the source. Then the files (file0...) will get updated only when the source change. But I need them also to get updated as they change themselves.

Comment: @flagadabla, perhaps I confused the situation. I was assuming that ´targetdir/file0´ is a target file. What are the actual source files and target files?

Comment: @flagadabla, I just tested making the source the script, and it only executes when the targetdir/file0 is removed, not when its updated. Its  not common practice to build a target when the target itself changes.

Comment: Right. I realize I'm trying to make a dependency cycle.

Comment: I actually want to run the command everytime a file in the directory changes.

Comment: @flagadabla, as you mentioned before, that will be difficult without creating dependency cycles. In addition to "somescript.sh", what is it that modifies the files in the directory? To reference all of the files in a directory, you can use the Glob() function. Keep in mind though that this wont work if the files havent been created yet.